# Php utf8_decode() not working with A&ndash;Z

Tags: php, utf-8, imagemagick

I am creating an Image with Image which shall have this text:
A–Z

but somehow the Long dash does not Show properly instead of the dash the string get shown.

How is it possible to make this line work:

```
utf8_decode('A&ndash;Z');
```

So that it Shows

A-Z with a Long dash.

Currently it just Returns the string in the parameter:

EDIT

The complete function:

```
protected function createImg($font = 'Helvetica-LT-55-Roman')
{
    $borderPadding = '50x0';
    $calcWidth     = 720;
    $calcSize      = $calcWidth . 'x520';

    $textEdu = utf8_decode('Lorem Ipsum A&ndash;Z Lorem Ipsum');

    $command = env('IMCONVERT', '') . ' -size ' . $calcSize . ' -background transparent -fill white -font ' . $font . ' -pointsize 22 -gravity west -interline-spacing 5 label:"' . $textEdu . '" -matte -bordercolor none -border ' . $borderPadding . ' -strokewidth 1 -stroke white -fill none -draw "line 203,100" ' . $this->path . 'menu\\ímg.png';

    return $command;
    // In my constructor() I just Shell_exec() the function and the Image gets created
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like it's working.  What is it doing wrong?

Comment: @FKEinternet I edited my question with more details

Answer (score 1):

You use a HTML entity here. So utf8 decode doesn't do anything. 
**To decode html entities you can use:**

```
html_entity_decode('A&ndash;Z');
```

Link:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: is it possible to use html_entity_decode('A&ndash;Z'); inside utf8_decode()? probably not or?

Comment: If you also want to do the utf8_decode you can place that inside the html_entity_decode()

Comment: Can you provide more script of the place you use this string?

Comment: Ok I added the function which creates the image

Comment: And if you change the utf8_decode() to html_entity_decode() it doesn't work?